# Does this recurrence relation of exponentials diverge?

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, divergent-series

Does the following recurrence relation diverge?
$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{e^{-x_k}}{(1+e^{-x_k})^2}$$
where $x_0 <0$.

I have plotted the first one million steps of the sequence using $x_0=-1$ alongside $-\log(k)$ and they look almost identical, suggesting that $x_k$ does indeed diverge.

[[image: Plot of the sequence alongside <span class=]$-log(k)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTFi6m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x _n \to x $. Then
$$0 = -\frac{e^{-x}}{(1 + e^{-x})^2} \implies e^{-x} = 0 
$$
so we get a contradiction.  Hence there $\not\exists x \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $x_n \to x$. On the other hand , $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence, so the only possible outcome is that $x_n \to -\infty$.